# Exporting class in react

Tags: reactjs, chartist.js

I'm using the boilerplate code for a chart using the Chartist library. The only moderation is that I added *export* before class:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ChartistGraph from '../index';

export class Pie extends React.Component {
  render() {

    var data = {
      labels: ['W1', 'W2', 'W3', 'W4', 'W5', 'W6', 'W7', 'W8', 'W9', 'W10'],
      series: [
        [1, 2, 4, 8, 6, -2, -1, -4, -6, -2]
      ]
    };

    var options = {
      high: 10,
      low: -10,
      axisX: {
        labelInterpolationFnc: function(value, index) {
          return index % 2 === 0 ? value : null;
        }
      }
   };

   var type = 'Bar'

   return (
     <div>
      <ChartistGraph data={data} options={options} type={type} />
     </div>
   )
 }
}
```

When I try to import the component in my parent component using:

```
import {Pie} from '../components/dashboardChart';
```

I get the following error:

> 54:28-41 "export 'default' (imported as 'ChartistGraph') was not found
>   in '../index'

Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: Are you opposed to using `export default Pie extends React.Component` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can export you Pie class as `export default class Pie extends React.Component {}`

And when you import it you can do so like this `import Pie from '../components/dashboardChart';`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, if I change the code with your suggestions I keep seeing the error: 54:28-41 "export 'default' (imported as 'ChartistGraph') was not found in '../index'. Does it have to do with the import statement: import ChartistGraph from '../index';

Comment: I changed a few things and now I get this error:
Module not found: Can't resolve 'chartist' in '/Users/username/react/project/node_modules/react-chartist/dist